# Blocking internet of an DHCP assigned static IP, but allowing internal LAN network to get to device

Tags: scripting, iptables, firewall, router, iptables-persistent

I have a Rasberry Pi that DHCP assigns a static IP address (Based on it's MAC address) at **192.168.2.12** with the Local gateway at 192.168.2.1, **I want to block internet traffic to it and from it**, but **I do** want **local LAN network traffic access to the Rasberry Pi (only internally)** .  How can I do this in **iptables** and the **AdvanceTomato router script?**  (If this is the best / easiest way).

[image: Router screen]

I tried the commands below:

```
######## block all internet to ip address but give access to LAN 
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.2.12 -j REJECT   

####### Restarts the firewall to update iptables without reboot of router
service firewall restart
```

But it seems to leak out to the internet

```
$ ping att.com

PING att.com (144.160.36.42) 56(84) bytes of data.
From unknown (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From unknown (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
From unknown (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=3 Destination Port Unreachable
From unknown (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=4 Destination Port Unreachable
64 bytes from att.com (144.160.36.42): icmp_seq=5 ttl=241 time=87.5 ms
From unknown (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=6 Destination Port Unreachable
64 bytes from att.com (144.160.36.42): icmp_seq=7 ttl=241 time=64.8 ms
From unknown (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=8 Destination Port Unreachable
64 bytes from att.com (144.160.36.42): icmp_seq=9 ttl=241 time=93.3 ms
```

**Am I using the correct commands / syntax to block the internet of a DHCP assigned static IP, but allow internal LAN network to get to the device?**

Comment: I would reject packet not from and not to 192.168.2.X. I can't post as answer as I don't know proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the default gateway for the Raspberry by running:

```
$ sudo ip route del default
```

Comment: I'm trying to keep it in the router iptables encase someone reboots it.  It's a assigned a static IP and a gateway when it's connected sorry for the confusion I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the router, use a reserved address for the Pi's MAC address(es) and don't assign a default route.  That way, whenever the pi reboots it will always get the same IP address but no route.

Then, in the firewall rules, you can simply deny all from that IP address... just in case someone manually assigns a default route.

Of course, someone smart enough and with root access to the pi could manually assign a different address and would get past your rules.  But, if you're just trying to casually prevent accidental or unintentional internet access from the pi, this suggestion should work.

Answer (score 0):

`DROP` anything that need to be forwarded from one network to another (Eg: Internet -> Lan || Lan -> Internet):

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

And `DROP` each packets from raspberry to hosts outside the lan and viceversa:

```
iptables -A INPUT ! -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT ! -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j DROP
```